# Can org.springframework.data.repository be Hibernate managed?

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-search

I've been using **Hibernate Search** to query database entries. For the majority of my cases I use a cron job that builds my index, but for one specific case I need the index to update immediately on entity change.
I noticed that while the *springframework.data.repository* updates the data correctly in the database, Hibernate does not perform an update of the respective entity in the index.

When I change my implementation to use the entity manager for this transaction (using *entitymanager.persist(x)* etc...) it also updates the index correctly.

I like the simplicity of the crud repository and I would like to stay consistent, so is there a way to let hibernate know of this change using the crud repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Data offers a [JPA-based CRUD repository](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-jpa), which will rely on JPA (Hibernate ORM) to perform CRUD operations and thus will allow Hibernate Search to update indexes automatically. You shouldn't need to implement calls to `entityManager.persist()`, etc. yourself.

If your CRUD repository does *not* use JPA (Hibernate ORM), then of course (as you noticed) Hibernate Search will not be aware of changes and will not update indexes.

You didn't specify how your CRUD repository was implemented exactly, so I suppose you're using the [Spring Data JDBC](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-jdbc) implementation? That's the only way I know of that would allow you to update your database in Spring Data without relying on JPA (Hibernate ORM).

I would recommend switching to the Spring Data JPA implementation at least for the entity that requires automatic, on-the-fly indexing.

If that's really not an option, I suppose you may be able to plug into Spring Data JDBC somehow (overriding CRUD methods, or using event listeners maybe), so that, every time an entity is changed:

- you load it using Hibernate ORM
- you explicitly index it using [fullTextSession.index()](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#_adding_instances_to_the_index) (in case of a create/update) or delete it from the index using [fullTextSession.purge()](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#_deleting_instances_from_the_index) (in case of delete).

I doubt performance will be very good, however. In particular, you'll be missing out on some optimizations in Hibernate Search that avoid reindexing when the change is only about properties that are not indexed.